# Android Studio - ¿Cómo cambiar el color de texto de un botón con selector XML?

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, botón, selectores

**Adjunto el código XML que uso como background de mi botón:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <stroke android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#ffffff"/>
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>

    </shape>

</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>

    </shape>

</item>

</selector>
```

Este código solo cambia el background de mi botón al ser presionado, pero el color de la letra permanece igual.

Lo que quiero lograr es que se cambie tanto el color del background como el color del texto de mi botón.

**Gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso tendrías que crear otro selector el cual sería configurado a tu botón:

```
<TextView
    ...
    ...
    ...
    android:textColor="@color/texto_selector"
    />
```

el selector debe ser creado dentro de `res/color`, aquí puedes hacer referencia a colores definidos dentro de `colors.xml`.

`texto_selector.xml`  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/green" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Otra vez más que logras solucionar un problema mio. Sos un gran aporte para esta comunidad Jorgesys. Muchisimas gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Me alegra poder ayudarte, saludos.